# for loop over a code without encountering the error

Tags: r

I have a chunk of r code, like below.

```
sce_1$use <- cellFilter(sce_1, 2500, 1000, 5)
sce_2$use <- cellFilter(sce_2, 2500, 1000, 5)
sce_3$use <- cellFilter(sce_3, 2500, 1000, 5)
sce_4$use <- cellFilter(sce_4, 3000, 1000, 5)
sce_5$use <- cellFilter(sce_5, 3000, 1000, 5)
```

This code works fine without any error or warning. To automate and clean the process I am trying to put this in a loop.

```
    sce_list=mget(sce)
    for (i in 1:length(paths))
    sce_list[i]$use <- cellFilter(sce_list[i], 3000, 1000, 5)

    The error I get

    Quitting from lines 209-213 (prototype.Rmd) 
    Error in sce$total_features : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
    Calls: <Anonymous> ... eval -> eval -> cellFilter -> filter_by_expr_features
    Execution halted
```

What else I have tried is:

```
    sce_list=mget(sce)
    for (i in 1:length(paths))
     get(paste0("sce_",i))$use <- cellFilter(sce[i], 2500, 1000, 5)

the error I get is

Quitting from lines 209-213 (prototype.Rmd) 
Error in sce$total_features : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors
Calls: <Anonymous> ... eval -> eval -> cellFilter -> filter_by_expr_features
Execution halted
```

On one of the suggestions from the comments, I used:

```
sce_list=mget(sce)
    for (i in 1:length(paths))
     sce_list[[i]]$use <- cellFilter(sce_list[[i]], 2500, 1000, 5)
```

This works fine. However, the next chunk of code that uses the previous part and used to work fine without looping of the previous chunk. However, now it throws up error.

```
automateFiltering <- function(sce){

    options(repr.plot.width=4, repr.plot.height=4)
    plotPCA(
        sce,
        size_by = "total_features", 
        pca_data_input = "pdata",
        shape_by = "use",
        detect_outliers = TRUE,
        return_SCE = TRUE
    )
}

sce_1 <- automateFiltering(sce_1)
 sce_2 <- automateFiltering(sce_2)
   sce_3 <- automateFiltering(sce_3)
    sce_4 <- automateFiltering(sce_4)
```

error:

```
    Quitting from lines 241-246 (prototype.Rmd) 
Error in .choose_vis_values(object, shape_by, cell_control_default = TRUE,  : 
  'use' not found in 'colnames(colData(x))'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... plotPCA -> .local -> plotReducedDim -> .choose_vis_values
Execution halted
```

Comment: A reproducible example would help...

Comment: `sce_list[i]$use` and `sce_list[i]` are wrong, it should be `sce_list[[i]]$use` and `sce_list[[i]]`. Also, why not `for(i in seq_along(sce_list))`?

Comment: @Christoph: I am really sorry, this is a small chunk of code from a pile. I am using the scater package. The guy before me used a lot of manual interventions and I am putting loops to make it more automated. It is difficult to give a reproducible example here.

Comment: Have you thought about `dput`? You only need a sample which reproduces the error... And yes, debugging Rmd is a pain.

Comment: @RuiBarradas: please see the updated question.

Comment: You now have a list. Shouldn't it be `sce_list[[1]] <- automateFiltering(sce_list[[1]])`, etc?

Comment: @RuiBarradas: Thank you again. It works fine with your sugeestion. However, when I loop it like this sce_list=mget(sce);
    for (i in seq_along(sce_list)){
    sce_list[[i]] <- automateFiltering(sce_list[[i]])}  It throw up the same error of use

Comment: @Angelo See my answer and if it doesn't solve the problem, please say so and I will delete it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure the following is an answer, the question is missing an example dataset.

Apparently, the `mget` instruction works.

```
sce_list <- mget(sce)
```

Then, you create a variable `use` in each list member object needed for the call to `automateFiltering`. And assign the return value of `automateFiltering` back to the **same** list member object.
This will destroy the previous contents of each `sce_list[[i]]`.

```
for (i in seq_along(sce_list)){
  sce_list[[i]]$use <- cellFilter(sce_list[[i]], 2500, 1000, 5)
  sce_list[[i]] <- automateFiltering(sce_list[[i]])
}
```

If you want to keep `sce_list`, assign the return value of `automateFiltering` to a **different** list, I name `sce_auto`.

```
sce_auto <- vector("list", length(sce_list))
for (i in seq_along(sce_list)){
  sce_list[[i]]$use <- cellFilter(sce_list[[i]], 2500, 1000, 5)
  sce_auto[[i]] <- automateFiltering(sce_list[[i]])
}
```

Comment: I have another related question. Could you please have a look here as well https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53456853/error-in-tmp-s4-class-object-in-my-r-markdown-file Many thanks in advance.