# unable to find an inherited method for function 'rowData' for signature '"logical"'

Tags: r, knitr

I have an R markdown code chunk that looks like this ( it is a small part of an extremely large code).

````
  filterLowExpressedGenes <- function(sce, cutoffCell, cutoffTranscript){

            apply(
                counts(sce[ , colData(sce)$use]), 
                1, 
                function(x) length(x[x > cutoffTranscript]) >= cutoffCell)
       }
        ```


    ```{r include=T}
        for (i in seq_along(sce_list))
          {
         print(rowData(sce_list[[i]])$use <- filterLowExpressedGenes(sce_list[[i]], 3, 5))
        }

        ```
````

`{r include=T}
   for (i in seq_along(sce_list))
    {
    print(table(rowData(sce_list[[i]])$use))
   }`

Till here all works fine and the output is:

```
## [1] "sce_1"
## 
## FALSE  TRUE 
## 31852  1842 
## [1] "sce_2"
## 
## FALSE  TRUE 
## 31009  2685 
## [1] "sce_3"
## 
## FALSE  TRUE 
## 31560  2134 
## [1] "sce_4"
## 
## FALSE  TRUE 
## 31697  1997
```

The next chunk that operates on the information processed in the previous chunks throws up error:

````
code: 
    ```{r include=T}
     for (i in seq_along(sce_list))
       {
          sce_list[[i]]$qc = sce_list[[i]][rowData(sce_list[[i]]$use), colData(sce_list[[i]]$use)]
      }

    ```
````

The error that I get is:

```
    Quitting from lines 331-345 (prototype.Rmd) 
Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable)  : 
  unable to find an inherited method for function 'rowData' for signature '"logical"'
Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> [ -> rowData -> <Anonymous>
Execution halted
```

I am sorry, I cannot provide you the sample workable data. As this is somewhat in between coding portion and that means that data has already gone under some sort of processing.

I am fully aware that it will require some guess work or hit and trial to figure out the solution. But any help/suggestion to make this work is welcome.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: You are placing the `$use`in the wrong place, I believe it should be `rowData(sce_list[[i]]$use)`, it is a member of the *list*, not from the *function's return value*.

Comment: use `cat()` to print out the value of `i` as you go along, you can see where the error occurs. Then inspect the relevant element of `sce_list` ...

Comment: @RuiBarradas: Hi, Thank you for your comment. I did move little forward. what I did was sce_list[[i]]$qc = sce_list[[i]][rowData(sce_list[[i]]$use), colData(sce_list[[i]]$use)] Now I have a new error message Error in (function (classes, fdef, mtable) : unable to find an inherited method for function 'rowData' for signature '"logical"' Calls: <Anonymous> ... withVisible -> eval -> eval -> [ -> rowData -> <Anonymous> Execution halted

Comment: What package contains `rowData`?

Comment: Hi, The package scater used for single cell experiment data analysis.